# Facebook buttons not working wordpress site

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Hello on my site here: http://www.awesomewasteofmoney.com

Whenever anyone likes my page it does not show up on facebook.  I tried to debugg it and I keep gettin gthis error from the debugger:

Object at URL 'http://www.awesomewasteofmoney.com/rubiks-cube-salt-n-pepper-mill/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '{}' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

I am using Facebook Revised Open Graph Meta Tag to assign the tags automatically.  Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Just to clear things up ive already tried <meta property="fb:admins" content="Myid" /> and i still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

`fb:admins` property should contain comma separated list of `id`.

In your case you should use `510048158` (user id) instead of `imzachjohnson` (username).

BTW, [Facebook Revised Open Graph Meta Tag](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/facebook-revised-open-graph-meta-tag/trunk/index.php) doesn't handle `fb:admins` meta so it's probably defined elsewhere and require manual change...